# Setting titlestring variable in vim

Tags: vim

I was trying the following from vimrc:

```
func StartUp()
    let l:myArg="Binu"
    let l:out=system('echo '.l:myArg)
    echo l:out
    let &titlestring=l:out
endFunc
```

However, this does not set the title, but does print "Binu". What I am trying is to set the title of my putty terminal depending on some derived value in the environment and can change. On change I could just invoke this function and reset my putty title. Any help welcome..

Thanks,
Binu

Comment: @sarnold: that should have been an answer.

Comment: @Chris, I tend to put my outright _guesses_ in comments, so the question doesn't look like it has an answer when people who might know better than me are browsing the list of questions. Sometimes they work, and I migrate them to answers; sometimes they fail, and I'll modify the question with the new information. But I'd hate for an incorrect guess to keep someone from thinking the question was taken care of already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `system(echo ..)` will add a newline to the variable; note the warning in `:help titlestring`:

> NOTE: Use of special characters in 'titlestring' may cause the display to be garbled (e.g., when it contains a CR or NL character).

Try `system('echo -n ..)` to not place a newline at the end of the string.